# Javascipt: static field in class create error

Tags: javascript, class, static

Both code on the image works in Chrome Desktop, but only the first code works on Chrome Mobile and Safari Mobile.

I checked on mozilla.org and there is no restriction for Static Fields. So, why I got some sort of Sintax Error on mobile?

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's a syntax error. "*I checked on mozilla.org and there is no restriction for Static Fields.*" - [MDN is quite clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) about this being only an experimental proposal?

Comment: You are right. This sintax is experimental. Sorry for missing that. Thanks a lot for the answer =)